# Is it possible to make your Qt application not lock file with itself while running?

Tags: c++, windows, qt

Is it possible to make your Qt application not lock file with itself while it is running?

Comment: what file are you talking about?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you mean locking the application's `exe` file itself, well, you can't prevent that. It is not related to Qt, this is a Windows behavior, unrelated to what you used to produce your application.

See this question: [Locking Executing Files: Windows does, Linux doesn't. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196897/locking-executing-files-windows-does-linux-doesnt-why) for why it happens.