# Does File.delete in java perform file locking?

Tags: java, file, synchronization

1. Does it lock the file before it deletes it?
2. Does it need to?
3. If it does not perform file locking how can I make it safe between multiple processes?

Comment: `safe between multiple processes`. It is called `thread safe`

Comment: @Cole Johnson what are you saying is incorrect

Comment: Keep in mind that file deletion is handled natively, so you won't necessarily encounter alike performance on differing operating systems.

Comment: A thread is a unit of work within a process.  A process is a unit of work in the operating system.  Multi-threading and Multi-processing are two very different things.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025721/java-file-locking)
will explain better. As far as I understand, deletion is an atomic operation so it does not need to lock the file. 
However, upon looking further, I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196897/locking-executing-files-windows-does-linux-doesnt-why)
which shows the OS dependent nature of the delete operation. On Windows, it will necessarily need the file to be without a lock to delete it while on Linux you can delete a file while another process is using it.

Comment: whether or not deletion will succeed on a locked file is operating system specific.

Comment: @OpDeCirkel - except being completely wrong about the File.delete part.