# Writing a scheduler in vertx to delete a file

Tags: java, vert.x

I want to write a method where i can return Future instead of void start

Also i want to apply lock while deleting the file.

public static **void start**(Vertx vertx) throws Exception { 
        vertx.setTimer(timeInterval, id -> {
            File file = new File(config.getStringProperty("file.upload.directory", null).get());

```
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            File[] files = file.listFiles();
            for (File fileName : files) {
                long diff = new Date().getTime() - fileName.lastModified();
        if (diff > config.getLongProperty("file.upload.cleanup.timer.millisecond", 0).get()) {
                    deleteFileUploads(fileName.getAbsolutePath());
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

private static void deleteFileUploads(String fileName) {
    File file = new File(fileName);
    LOGGER.debug("Name of the file to be deleted"+fileName);
    file.delete();
}
```

}

Instead of this I want my function to be like 
public static **Future start**(Vertx vertx) throws Exception { 
}

Comment: Just a note about the deleteFileUploads method: it executes blocking code and you're calling it from a timer callback. You should wrap invocation in vertx#executeBlocking.

Answer (score 0):

So just change void to be what you want to return instead? What is the problem?

```
public static Future start(Vertx vertx) throws Exception { vertx.setTimer(timeInterval, id -> { File file = new File(config.getStringProperty("file.upload.directory", null).get());

        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            File[] files = file.listFiles();
            for (File fileName : files) {
                long diff = new Date().getTime() - fileName.lastModified();
        if (diff > config.getLongProperty("file.upload.cleanup.timer.millisecond", 0).get()) {
                    deleteFileUploads(fileName.getAbsolutePath());
                }
            }
        }

    });
    //add new line to do your return here. If you want to get something out of the info above then use a public variable?
    return new Future()......;//define and return what you want here?
}
```

As for the file locking try searching other questions. For example see here:
[Does File.delete in java perform file locking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007365/does-file-delete-in-java-perform-file-locking) and here: [Locking Executing Files: Windows does, Linux doesn't. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196897/locking-executing-files-windows-does-linux-doesnt-why)